# Python class attributes inside a method

Tags: python, class

Consider the following code, I want you to explain why the code doesn't work because I have seen others to assign the class attributes outside `__init__` and 
call the attributes in one method from another, what is wrong with mine. The following three prints all result error saying the class has no attributes whatsoever.

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, age, height):
        self.age = age
        self.height = height

    def weight_kg(self):
        self.weight = 60

    def ratio_kg2height(self):
        self.ratio = self.weight / self.height
        return self.ratio


mike = Person(23, 170)
print mike.weight
print mike.ratio_kg2height()
print mike.ratio
```

Comment: `mike.weight` isn't initialised until you call `weight_kg`. You'd need to make it a property.

Comment: Why do you believe that `weight` is going to be defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not defining the `weight` attribute in the `__init__` method, since you dont call `weight_kg` method before accesing the attribute it is not available.

You have some options here, the basic one is to initialize it first, you can simply call your methods in the `__init__` method:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, age, height):
        self.age = age
        self.height = height
        self.weight_kg()
        self.ratio_kg2height()

    ...
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/AquaVelvetyTheories)

Comment: When should I use the "hidden attributes" just as self.weight in this case?

Comment: @buzhidao what do you mean by "hidden attribute"? If you don't want an attribute error, then don't try to access an attribute until it is defined.

Comment: those are not hidden attributes, there are just late initialized.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga when should I use the late initialized attributes?

Comment: @buzhidao, just use them when you are sure you will not need them in memory until some point...depends on what is the purpouse of your code. I would recommend not to do this, it can be a nightmare to maintain this kind of code, think of a coworker searching for the attributes of your class in all the methods for example. It is better to explicitly declare them, at least with default values, None or some kind of flag.

Comment: @buzhidao again, if you try to access them *before they are initialized* you will get an `AttributeError`. What do you not understand, exactly?

Comment: As you suggests, will it be a better practice to add two lines `self.weight=None self.ratio=None` before `self.weight_kg()`?

Comment: @buzhidao, this is just personal opinion, but yes. Or in this case `self.weight = 60` and just return it in the function if you want